# Aerospike limiting records by lexicographic order

Tags: aerospike

Can Aerospike get records by lexicographic order.For example if U want all the records that start with "a" then U like to search for bin >="a" AND bin <="az"

Answer (score 1):

aerospike support UDF modules(in LUA and C language) https://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/developing_lua_modules.html
which can serve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

[User-Defined Functions](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/udf_guide.html) written in Lua extend the core functionality of Aerospike. You would create a [stream UDF](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/developing_stream_udfs.html) and attach it to a [query](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/query.html).

One best practice for stream UDFs in Aerospike is to eliminate as many records as possible before passing the results into the UDF, so in this case I would create another bin to hold a prefix (first letter, or a substring, depending on your use case) and build a secondary index on it. The idea is that the query portion should return as small of a subset as you can reliably. For your example the prefix can be a single character, you can add a new bin 'firstchar' to the records in the set, then [build](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.index_string_create) a secondary index on it.

The stream UDF module would look something like:

```
local function range_filter(bin_name, substr_from, substr_to)
    return function(record)
        local val = record[bin_name]
        if type(val) ~= 'string' then
            return false
        end
        if val >= substr_from and val <= substr_to then
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end

local function rec_to_map(record)
    local xrec = map()
    for i, bin_name in ipairs(record.bin_names(record)) do
        xrec[bin_name] = xrec[bin_name]
    end
    return xrec
end


function str_between(stream, bin_name, substr_from, substr_to)
    return stream : filter(range_filter(bin_name, substr_from, substr_to)) : map(rec_to_map)
end
```

In the Python client you'd invoke it as follows:

```
import aerospike
from aerospike import predicates as p

# instantiate the client and connect to the cluster, then:
query = client.query('test', 'this')
query.where(p.equals('firstchar', 'a'))
query.apply('strrangemod', 'str_between', ['a','az'])
```